# how to build xv6 OS on qemu

Tags: xv6

I am trying to build XV6 OS on linux using QEMU
but whenever I type on the terminal make QEMU-nox it gives an error "no rule to make target qemu-nox"
I know i have properly installed qemu.
can anyone please tell me what is wrong ?
also what will be the command to get the XV6 running ??

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to use QEMU, I believe that

```
make qemu
```

should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

First of all navigate to the directory of xv6 then,
Try to use this command :

`make`

`make qemu`